# Burn arduino bootloader using ubuntu 16

Tags: arduino-ide, bootloader, ubuntu

I get the following error when I try to burn the arduino bootloader on an atmega328 mcu:

```
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0xfd != 0x05
```

I am using an Arduino as ISP programmer. My computer runs Ubuntu 16.

This did not happen when I was using Ubuntu 14. I also tested it on another machine with Ubuntu 14 and this error does not appear. Seems to be something with Ubuntu 16. I installed Arduino IDE using the out of the box repo.

The avrdude command launched by the IDE is:

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude -C/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0x05:m -Uhfuse:w:0xde:m -Ulfuse:w:0xff:m
```

Am I safe replacing the -Uefuse:w:0x05:m with -Uefuse:w:0xfd:m ?? If answer is yes how can I get the IDE to do this correctly?

Uploading a sketch works pretty well.

Comment: This is not a real answer.
I have the same problem on Os X, but I can upload sketch via "upload using programmer", but this way I have no bootloader.
Problem arises only when trying to install boot loader.
I didn't have this problem some years ago on Linux Debian.
I your problem is solved, please let us know.

Comment: There is no functional differences between an efuse setting of 0x05 and 0xfd, as only the three lowest bits actually exist.  Your actual problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and I think I have solved it.

In boards.txt file, I had:

```
##############################################################

diecimila.name=Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila

diecimila.upload.tool=avrdude diecimila.upload.protocol=arduino

diecimila.bootloader.tool=avrdude diecimila.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
diecimila.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
diecimila.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

diecimila.build.f_cpu=16000000L diecimila.build.board=AVR_DUEMILANOVE
diecimila.build.core=arduino diecimila.build.variant=standard

## Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila w/ ATmega328
## --------------------------------------------- diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328=ATmega328

diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.upload.maximum_size=30720
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.upload.maximum_data_size=2048
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.upload.speed=57600

diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
 diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328.hex

diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.build.mcu=atmega328p

## Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila w/ ATmega168
## --------------------------------------------- diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168=ATmega168

diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.upload.maximum_size=14336
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.upload.maximum_data_size=1024
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.upload.speed=19200

diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.bootloader.high_fuses=0xdd
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x00
 diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.bootloader.file=atmega/ATmegaBOOT_168_diecimila.hex

diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega168.build.mcu=atmega168

##############################################################
```

I have replaced the line containing:

```
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x05
```

with:

```
diecimila.menu.cpu.atmega328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0xFD
```

Everything is ok now.

I can install boot loader on an ATMEGA328P (with an usbasp programmer), and I can install sketchs after that (via usb serial).

I don't know if it's the best way to solve the problem, but it works.
Hope this will help you, if not already solved.

Comment: As there are only 3 bits in the extended fuses of an ATmega328p, 0x05 and 0xFD are actually the same value as far as the bits that exist.  Different ways of handling the non-existent bits account for on the only difference, which is irrelevant.